# Algebra: add two matrices

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Well I'm trying to add two matrices but my math is wrong and I think I'm out of ideas on how to get it right. I feel absolutely stupid that I can't figure this out, but my head hurts and I'm all out of options

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AddMatrices
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int N = 3;

      System.out.print("Enter matrix1: ");
      double[][] matrix1 = new double[3][3];
      for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < matrix1[i].length; j++) {
            matrix1[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
         }
      }

      System.out.print("Enter matrix2: ");
      double[][] matrix2 = new double[3][3];
      for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < matrix1[i].length; j++) {
            matrix2[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
         }
      }

      double[][] resultMatrix = addMatrix(matrix1, matrix2);
      System.out.println("The addition of the matrices is ");
      printResult(matrix1, matrix2, resultMatrix, '+');
   }

   public static double[][] addMatrix(double[][] m1, double[][] m2)
   {
      double[][] result = new double[m1.length][m1[0].length];
      for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++)
            m1[i][j] += m2[i][j];
      }
      return result;
   }

   public static void printResult(double[][] m1, double[][] m2, double[][] m3, char op)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < m1[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + m1[i][j]);
         }
         if (i == m1.length / 2)
            System.out.print(" " + op + " ");
         else {
            System.out.print(" ");
         }
         for (int j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + m2[i][j]);
         }
         if (i == m1.length / 2)
            System.out.print(" = ");
         else {
            System.out.print(" ");
         }
         for (int j = 0; j < m3[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + m3[i][j]);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What are the expected results, and what results are you getting instead? Also, take a walk, does wonders to clear the head.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar +1 for take a walk. I usually pace around my room like a madman :)

Comment: The result is suppose to be a uniformed printout of matrix 1 , 2 , and the result of adding them. My print results is coming out all crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
m1[i][j] += m2[i][j];
```

do:

```
result[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
```

Comment: Ha! I see! Dang, Sometimes I feel like I am no good at this.So simple